# How do I fix these console errors?

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to fix this for a while and cannot fix it. I have tried deleting and reinstalling react-dom, react-router, and react-router-dom. Please let me know if there are any other solutions. I am new to React and this seems to be a long bump in the road.

```js
import { toast, ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './Components/Home/home';
import Profile from './Components/Profile/profile';
import SidePanel from './Components/SidePanel/sidePanel';
import SignIn from './Components/Signin/signin';
import Signup from './Components/Signup/Signup';


class App extends Component {
  showToast = (type, message) => {
    switch (type) {
      case 0:
        toast.warning(message)
        break;
      case 1:
        toast.success(message)
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  render(props) {
    return (< Router >
      <ToastContainer
        autoClose={2000}
        hideProgressBar={true}
        position={toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER}
      />
      <Routes>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={prop => <Home {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/signin"
          render={prop => <SignIn showToast={this.showToast} {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/signup"
          render={prop => <Signup showToast={this.showToast} {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/profile"
          render={prop => <Profile showToast={this.showToast} {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/chat"
          render={prop => <SidePanel showToast={this.showToast} {...props} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    );
  };
};

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Console Errors:
[image: Console Errors]

Comment: whitch version of react router you're using ?

Comment: This is the newest version of react-router I am pretty sure.

Comment: so change `import { Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';` to `import {BrowserRouter as  Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: Share the errors, no screenshot of errors! That being said, the errors didnt happen in the file you shared. There's no mention of 'pathname'

Comment: What's your react router dom version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change :**

```
import { Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
```

**to :**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
```